# Who are the forest deities mentioned in the Aranya Kanda?

Tags: ramayana, gods, goddess

According to the Valmiki Ramayana, Ravana abducts Sita by carrying her forcibly. By looking at Ravana grabbing Sita, forest deities were terrorised.

> tam dṛṣṭvā giri śṛṃga ābham tīkṣṇa daṃṣṭram mahā bhujam |
>   prādravan mṛtyu saṃkāśam bhaya ārtā vana devatāḥ ||
>
> On seeing him who grabbed Seetha, who has incisive fangs, mightily armed and who is shining forth like a mountain crest and similar to Death, the forest deities quickly fled away terrorised by his terrorism. [[Aranya Kanda Sarga 49 shloka 18](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga49/aranya_49_frame.htm)]

I found out there is a goddess of forests and animals named [Aranyani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aranyani) in the RigVeda. But Valmiki maharshi uses plural "vana devatāḥ" which indicates there could be a group of gods or goddesses.

Who are the forest deities mentioned in this instance? Is there any detail available about these deities in other chapters of Ramayana, Purana or other literature?